# Qt5Cored.dll missing when trying to run application

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013

I'm using **Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate**.

My Qt version is **5.2.1**

Am using a specific build for VS2013 which I obtained from [here](http://www.tver-soft.org/qt64).

Now, what I did:

1. Created a new Qt Application from Visual Studio.
2. Typed in my logic and the code.
3. Built it successfully in x64 Debug mode.
4. Ran the application successfully.

Everything good so far.

Now the problem:

1. I restart my Visual Studio and load the project.
2. It is built successfully (in x64 Debug).
3. Now, am unable to run it. I get the error:

   ```
   The program can't start because Qt5Cored.dll is missing from your computer.
   Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
   ```

It ran the first time when I created the application. Now it won't run.

I tried simulating the problem, and this happens everytime. Runs the first time, and doesn't run after Visual Studio restart.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding $QTDIR\bin to your library path. You could also copy the required dlls to your executables working directory.

Comment: Tried that, but not working.
My question is, if it worked the first time, why did it stop working? I didn't change anything.

Comment: Eventually the IDE did not save the Runtime Environment correctly.

Comment: Yes.. But how do I make sure this doesn't happen again?

Comment: Ok, I found that in the Debugging->Environment variable, the macro `$(QTDIR)` is missing. That is why it's not getting required dlls.
How do I add a macro there? Currently I've kept full path.

Comment: It's strange that the same macro is working in Linker and C\C++ properties!

Comment: Try replacing $QTDIR with the full path to your Qt Installation

Comment: Yes yes. Currently I've kept the full path and its working good.
Still in doubt as to why such a thing is happening. :-/

Comment: and you are not mixing 32 and 64 bit binaries, right?

Comment: @LaszloPapp Nopes. Not mixing. Am working only with 64 bit binaries.
Visual Studio resets my `Debugging->Environment` variable everytime. I need to set full path.

Comment: This is an issue with the environment set up/used by Visual Studio. A simple way to check the environment is to add an *External Tool* (*Tools* -> *External Tools...*: *Add* and set *Command:* to `cmd.exe`, *Arguments:* to `/c set`, and tick the *Use Output window* option.) With this tool you can investigate the current environment used by Visual Studio, particularly the `QTDIR` and `PATH` variables.

Answer (score 3):

From project properties you have to go to debugging -> Environment -> and write PATH=qt5 dll paths Or you have to put the dlls next to the exe.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you in debug mode. Probably in that case `Qt5Cored.dll` (with a `d` in the name) was used. Maybe in the second build, you build in release mode, and for some reason `Qt5Core.dll` is not found in the PATH.

Comment: Please read. It is asking for `Qt5Cored.dll` when am trying 2nd time. Means I'm in debug mode only! What is the solution here?

Comment: In your post it actually says Qt5Core.dll ;P Nevertheless, both are located in the same directory

Comment: Yeah.. my mistake.. :D Sorry.. Was building in debug only.

Answer (score -1):

here is what i did and it worked :D
first : make sure you are building a release version not a debug version 
second : it asked for the qt5core.dll when you copy it to the same path of your program it may ask for other *.dll files so i put the program in the folder containing all the dlls :D 
which is 
C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\mingw53_32\bin
or according to your installation ..it worked well
any way this folder (as i think) contains all  DLL libraries you may need with your program 
so to know what exactly you need from it try to start your program many times in another location and in every time you will know another dll needed according to your programming ..
that method worked but i think there may be a more cleaver solutions we have to dig for :)

Comment: that was using Qt creator , open source version